# Add-in for Outlook (both live and desktop) for creating a distribution list

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

My request is quite trivial. I receive a lot of mails from recruiters and I want to create a distribution list with all addresses. As I developer, I don't want to cut and paste their addresses from an email to the distribution list.

Then, my idea is to create an add-in that reads from a folder each email and insert the address in the mailing list.

Is there a simple way to create an add-in for Outlook Web and desktop where I can select the folder and the distribution list and automatically running when there is a new email in that particular folder?

Answer (score 0):

We recommend you to have a look at our documentation on [Build your first Outlook Add-in](https://o365exchange.visualstudio.com/O365%20Core/_queries/edit/1594285/?triage=true) and
use of [Outlook Rest API on Outlook Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api) to create an Add-in as per your requirement.
Currently the feature:Running Add-ins on receiving new mails, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.